# Looping through a row of emails

Tags: php, mysql

I need to hide certain accounts from the admin function.

Currently, eash account is listed for the admin. However, I would like all emails that end with, lets say, gmail.com to be hidden until I ask for them to be listed with the others.

This is the code for the emails I have:

```
    if(empty($resLine['ord_conEmail'])){
        $resLine['ord_conEmail'] = "Account {$resLine['ord_account']}";
    }
```

And the larger of the code is:

```
  $buffer .= "
        <div id=\"catDetail\">
            <h1>Orders Listing$pnStr</h1>
            <div>
                <table class=\"roundTableFormat\">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Order ID</th>
                            <th>Order Date</th>
                            <th>Cust. Email Address</th>
                            <th>Order Total</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>";

forEach($res as $resLine){
    if($resLine['ord_date'] > mktime() - 86400){
        //24 hours
        $resLine['ord_date'] = date("D jS - g:iA", $resLine['ord_date']);
    }else if($resLine['ord_date'] > mktime() - 259200){
        //OLD:display Day of Week for last five days (60*60*24*5=432000 sec
        //New: 3 days = 259200
        $resLine['ord_date'] = date("D jS - g:iA", $resLine['ord_date']);
    }else{
        //display full date
        $resLine['ord_date'] = date("M j, Y", $resLine['ord_date']);
    }

    $resLine['ord_total'] = "$".number_format($resLine['ord_total'], 2);

    if(empty($resLine['ord_conEmail'])){
        $resLine['ord_conEmail'] = "Account {$resLine['ord_account']}";
    }

    $buffer .= "
            <tr>
                <td class=\"ds br\">{$resLine['ord_id']}</td>
                <td class=\"al ls br\">{$resLine['ord_date']}</td>
                <td class=\"al ls\">{$resLine['ord_conEmail']}</td>
                <td class=\"ar bl br\">{$resLine['ord_total']}</td>
                <td class=\"ds \">
                    <a href=\"?action=orders&ordview={$resLine['ord_id']}\">View</a>
                    <a href=\"?action=orders&ordprint={$resLine['ord_id']}\">Print</a>
                </td>
            </tr>";
}
```

How can I create a loop to hide the certain emails from showing up?

Comment: That's pretty basic stuff, you check for the address at the start of your `foreach` loop and don't continue if it is not what you want. What exactly are you stuck with?

Comment: I am stuck with the entire process. I am a web designer, not a developer, but was asked to help in this area. So, I do not know how to write the code at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hash table (associative array) where you store the e-mail domains that you want to omit.

```
$domains = array(
    'gmail.com' => true
);
```

You can add a conditional statement that checks if the domain was set. It would be inserted before the line that buffers the html to be printed.

```
$email = $resLine['ord_conEmail'];

// Assumes e-mail address is correctly formatted: user@domain
$result = explode('@', $email);
$domain = $result[1];

if (isset($domains[$domain]) && $domains[$domain]) {
    continue; // Skip row
}
```

Comment: I will continue to play with this, but I am getting an error at:
Undefined variable: email
Undefined offset: 1

thank you very much for your assistance!

Comment: @user1324759 Sorry about that. $email was supposed to be the email address that you're checking. I added a line that assigns it using the value from the row.

Comment: isset($domains[$domain]) && $domains[$domain] is the same as !empty($domains[$domain]) (and a tad more readable imho). Good solution otherwise!